Build gcc raise err: Makefile:1087: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
I use following code
I git clone gcc-13.2.0 and run contrib/download_prerequisites
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/dist --disable-multilib --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace=yes
make -j$(nproc)

it raise err:
Makefile:1087: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

I find the Makefile:1087 is:
all:
    [ -f stage_final ] || echo stage3 > stage_final # here is Makefile:1087
    @r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    $(MAKE) $(RECURSE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) `cat stage_final`-bubble
    @: $(MAKE); $(unstage)
    +@r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    if [ -f stage_last ]; then \
      TFLAGS="$(STAGE$(shell test ! -f stage_last || sed s,^stage,, stage_last)_TFLAGS)"; \
      $(MAKE) $(TARGET_FLAGS_TO_PASS) all-host all-target; \
    else \
      $(MAKE) $(RECURSE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) \
        $(PGO_BUILD_GEN_FLAGS_TO_PASS) all-host all-target \
        ; \
    fi \
    && :

How to make gcc build pass, I find many similar questions in stackoverflow but cannot fix my err

Many reasons cause this err
default "make" out merge stdout and stderr, so it's hard to find err in long out
use following cli split stdout and stderr
make -j$(nproc) > /tmp/out.log 2> /tmp/err.log
see err.log for err detail
in my case, it has following stderr
configure: error: `CC' has changed since the previous run:
  configure: former value:
    `/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include '
  configure: current value:
    `/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include -fchecking=1'
configure: error: in `/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libquadmath':
  configure: error: changes in the environment can compromise the build
configure: error: run `make distclean' and/or `rm ./config.cache' and start over
configure: error: `CC' has changed since the previous run:
  configure: former value:
    `/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include '
  configure: current value:
    `/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/dist/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include -fchecking=1'
configure: error: in `/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnuTo resolve the issue, you can follow these steps:

1. Open a terminal or command prompt.
2. Navigate to the directory `/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0`.
3. Run the command `make distclean` to clean the build artifacts.
4. Remove the `config.cache` file by running the command `rm ./config.cache`.
5. Start the configuration process again by running the `configure` script or command that you were using previously.

By performing these steps, you should be able to reset the configuration and continue with the build process without the `CC` change error.

it say:
1. Open a terminal or command prompt.
    2. Navigate to the directory `/home/roroco/Dropbox/cpp/cpp-global-deps/gcc-13.2.0`.
    3. Run the command `make distclean` to clean the build artifacts.
    4. Remove the `config.cache` file by running the command `rm ./config.cache`.
    5. Start the configuration process again by running the `configure` script or command that you were using previously.
    

so I make distclean and rm config.cache and try build gcc again, it fixed

Good general advice for debugging failed builds but not an answer to the
question. Should be a comment. The question is unanswerable for lack of
a build log.
